# Reading component parameters and setting defaults

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm pulling my hair on this because it should be simple.

I'm trying to create a component and set its default properties.

```
<CustomComp text="Some text" color2="0x939202" value="4.5" />
```

But when  I initialize it, the parameters still don't register.

I do like this:

```
[Bindable] private var myColor2:uint = 0x000000;
[Bindable] private var myValue:Number = 10.0;
```

But it just gives me the default, all the time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the private vars have different names than the vars in the CustomComp tag.

Comment: That wasn't the issue, but I found other leads that put me on the right track. Thanks for responding.